# Web Development: PHP both Client and Server Side?

Tags: php, server-side

When PHP is embedded in HTML what is happening?
Isn't it the case that the html response object is interpreted in the browser, so how does the browser handle the php? Does it make a separate request?

PHP is a server side language that can be embedded in client side languages?

Comment: PHP is server-side only.

Comment: If you're referring to `<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>` - that statement is parsed server-side and the resulting HTML is passed to the client. No PHP is executed on the client

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126684/how-does-php-interact-with-html-and-vice-versus

Comment: @j08691 looks like a possible duplicate to me

Answer (score 2):

Here is what happens:

1. Someone goes to your site in their browser. This triggers at HTTP request to your server
2. Your server decides how it wants to handle the request. Let's say you're using Apache: by default then, this is to serve the `index` page within your `DocumentRoot`
3. Let's assume your index page is `index.php`. On the server, all PHP code within `index.php` is executed once. After it has executed, the HTML result of that page is served to the client
4. Once served to the client, the only thing that can modify the page is JavaScript. PHP only runs on the server. No PHP code will be sent to the client.
5. If your JavaScript wants to dynamically edit the page with information from the server without a reload, it can perform an AJAX request to the server. This entails the JavaScript making a network request to an endpoint (let's say, `getNames.php`). `getNames.php` runs on the server, and returns it's result (usually in the form of `echo <something>` back to the JavaScript, which can then edit the page based on the received data.

Questions?

Comment: No ur response is very clearly and exactly what I needed to know. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. The browser issues an HTTP request to the server
2. The server reads the URL and resolves it (usually to a file with the same name)
3. The server recognises (usually by matching file extensions) the file as containing a PHP program
4. The server passes the program through a PHP compiler and executes it
5. The server sends the output of the program (usually along with some extra HTTP response headers) to the browser

The PHP source code is never sent to the browser. Only one request is made (unless the output of the PHP is, for instance, an HTML document that tells the browser to load (for example) images).