# How to scrape content of another opened tab in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have two tabs opened in Google chrome, In first tab, i have a website opened and accessing a page after login in that website,

second tab is to see the output of my php program,

I want to scrape the content of the page opened in 1st tab of the browser.. Can I do that in php?

Currently i am using file_get_contents("https://example.com"); but it gives only the content of the home page of website, but i want the content of the page shows after login in that website, how can i achieve this in php or js (note: that website is not using jquery by default)?

Comment: You can't interact with google chrome tabs from PHP. I mean there's no standard way without any hacks I'm aware of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does PHP interact with HTML and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126684/how-does-php-interact-with-html-and-vice-versa)

Comment: You probably should take a look at what webkit is, or solve it with google chrome extension somehow. Sometimes webkit is overkill however and you can get away with simple HTTP requests using cURL or something like that

Comment: Even if you write JS code for such a task, it won't work. Thats a basic security topic for browsers

Comment: @NicoHaase In some browsers I think you can disable this security. I remember I was doing something like this in firefox but it worked only with developer/ESR edition

Comment: Technically if you embedded PHP in chromium which would require  you to have your custom browser it could be possible too :P

Comment: Try Using Selenium with php by that you can achieve your thing

Comment: @NicoHaase and for good reason. Imagine if any page could simply access another tab where perhaps you have your banking info open... nightmare.

Comment: If i read questions like this, i always have the feeling , that there is a deeper meaning behind of that, which for whatever reason op doesn't want to share with us . imho the way you ask this kind of question is bizarre...