# How to combine html with php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to connect php with html form. Currently my code looks like this:

```
<? php

$path = "books /";
$books = opendir ($path);
while (($book = readdir ($books))! == false)
{
    if (substr ($book, -4) === ".txt")
    {
        $filePath = $path. $book;
        // echo $book;

        $readFile = fopen ($filePath, "r+") or die ("Permission error");
        $infoBook = fread ($readFile, filesize($filePath));
        echo $infoBook;
        echo "<br>";
        $writeInfo = fwrite ($readFile, filesize($filePath));
        fclose ($readFile);
    }
    
}
closedir ();

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Books Form </title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
        <script src = "jquery-3.6.0.js"> </script>
        <style>
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method = "post" action="<? php $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF'];?>" id = "bookform">
            <label for = "books"> </label>
            <select name = "book" id = "books" form = "bookform">
                
                <option value = "blank"> </option>
                <option value = "Atlas_chmur.txt"> Cloud Atlas </option>
                <option value = "Dune.txt"> Dune </option>
            </select> <br> <br>
            <button style = "position: relative; left: 240px" type = "submit" form = "form" value = "<? php $readFile = fopen ($book," r + ");?>" name = "click" > Load </button> <br> <br>
            <textarea name = "info" rows = "30" cols = "100">
                <? php echo $infoBook?>
            </textarea> <br>
            <button type = "submit" form = "form" value = "Submit"> Save </button> <br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't really know how to add files returned in a loop to combobox ( ) so that I can select a specific one and display it later in 
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Don't you get errors when you leave a space between the `$` sign and your variable names?

Comment: What's your exact question about this code? Is this even working without syntax errors?

Comment: Please check on this question it has all the answers for your question [How does PHP interact with HTML and vice versa? ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126684/how-does-php-interact-with-html-and-vice-versa)

Comment: And please add this line to your code ``ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`` your php script has a lot of syntax errors to show them add this line of code

Comment: @WardNsour if the script has syntax errors that prevent it from executing, then `ini_set` inside it won’t do anything either. This needs to be set in the central PHP configuration, if you want it to have any effect on script with parse errors.

Comment: @Kasia13130 _“When inserting the code into the post, I formatted it weird”_ - then _edit_ your question and correct it, please.

Comment: Instead of doing `echo $infoBook`, add that value to an array. And then write a loop that goes over this array in the location where you want to output the options.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in PHP simply like that

```
<?php for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++): ?>
  <option value="<?= $x ?>"><?= $x ?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

at each iteration in the loop, an option will be added. you can use the same principle with your array

Comment: What is "it"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Also, how does the given code even work? Is there any good reason to have eleven elements in a dropdown, with distinct names, but equal values?

Comment: it's just an example of how to combine HTML with PHP. that's what he asked for.